# Is there a simpler way of checking if one enum has a particular value and others some other values

Tags: c#

A User in my system can have Email, Mobile or Phone and based on the values passed I am checking some conditions and then setting the ContactDataStatus (which is an enum) for each. I am then checking the ContactDataStatus to determine whether the provided contact details were valid.

The enum has the following definition

```
public enum ContactDataStatus
    {
        ExistsButUnverified = 1, 
        ExisitsAndVerified = 2, 
        IsValid = 3, 
        IsUninitialized = 4
    }
```

I wrote the following if conditions to set isValid variable

```
    isValid = false;
    if (emailStatus == ContactDataStatus.IsValid && 
       (mobileStatus == ContactDataStatus.IsValid || 
        mobileStatus == ContactDataStatus.IsUninitialized) 
        && (phoneStatus == ContactDataStatus.IsValid || 
        phoneStatus == ContactDataStatus.IsUninitialized))
    {
        isValid = true;
    }
    else if (mobileStatus == ContactDataStatus.IsValid && 
    (emailStatus == ContactDataStatus.IsValid || 
    emailStatus == ContactDataStatus.IsUninitialized) && 
    (phoneStatus == ContactDataStatus.IsValid || 
    phoneStatus == ContactDataStatus.IsUninitialized))
    {
       isValid = true;
    }
    else if (phoneStatus == ContactDataStatus.IsValid && 
    (emailStatus == ContactDataStatus.IsValid || 
    emailStatus == ContactDataStatus.IsUninitialized) && 
    (mobileStatus == ContactDataStatus.IsValid || 
    mobileStatus == ContactDataStatus.IsUninitialized))
    {
      isValid = true;
    }
```

Is there a simpler/shorter way of writing this?

Comment: It would be simpler to *read* if you'd use multiple lines for each condition instead of making us scroll each time... as well as describing in words what ever you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Apologies, I edited to make it readable and added what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would help if you told us what the values were for the enum. It sounds like you want *at least one* of the values to be valid, and *all* of the values to either be uninitialized or valid. So one way of expressing that would be:

```
var statuses = new[] { emailStatus, mobileStatus, phoneStatus };
bool valid = statuses.Any(x => x == ContactDataStatus.IsValid) &&
             statuses.All(x => x == ContactDataStatus.IsValid ||
                               x == ContactDataStatus.IsUninitialized);
```

Or if the status enum is just `IsValid`, `IsUninitialized` and (say) `IsInvalid`, and you knew that the values would *actually* be in that set, you could write:

```
var statuses = new[] { emailStatus, mobileStatus, phoneStatus };
bool valid = statuses.Any(x => x == ContactDataStatus.IsValid) &&
             statuses.All(x => x != ContactDataStatus.IsInvalid);
```

Also, I'd suggest that you removed the "is" prefix from each of the enum values - it's just fluff which makes the code harder to read IMO.

Comment: I added all the possible values of the enum.

Answer (score 0):

```
var statuses = new[] { emailStatus, mobileStatus, phoneStatus };
bool isValid = statuses
    .Any(s => s == ContactDataStatus.IsValid && statuses.Except(new[] { s }).All(o => o == ContactDataStatus.IsValid || o == ContactDataStatus.IsUninitialized));
```

Comment: No, I believe that will give `false` if the values are all `IsValid`, when it should give `true`.